# passar id do elemento filho para o elemento pai

Tags: javascript, css, react

estou precisando da ajuda de vcs.

tenho minha pagina principal e um componente de card, o que eu gostaria era que a cada hover no card o backgroundImage da pagina principal mudasse de acordo com o card, pensei em fazer pelo id, mas como pegar esse id na pagina principal?

Esse é o meu card

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import spidermanList from '../data/spidermanList.json'
import '../styles/componentes/Card.css'


function Card() {
  function MouseEnter(event){
  
    console.log('entrei')
  }
  function MouseLeave(event){
   
    console.log('sai')
  }
  
  return(
    <>
      {spidermanList.map((spiderman, index) => (
          <Link to={`/Spiderman/${spiderman.movies[0].id}`} key={index} id={`spiderman-${index + 1}`} className='card'
          onMouseEnter={MouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={MouseLeave}>
            <img src={spiderman.coverBackground} alt={spiderman.name} className='card__background'/>
            <img src={spiderman.coverImg} alt={spiderman.name} className='card__image'/>
            <h2 className='card__title'>{spiderman.name}</h2>
          </Link>
        ))}
    </>
      
  )
}

export default Card
```

Essa é a pagina pricipal:

```
import '../styles/pages/Home.css'

//Importer les composants 
import Navbar from "../componentes/Navbar"
import CarouselCards from "../componentes/CarouselCards"


function Home(){
 
  document.title="Spiderman Multiverse - Page d'accueil"
  
  return(
    <div className="body">
      <Navbar />
      <CarouselCards/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Porque na verdade queria que no onMouseEnter a imagem mudasse e no onMouseLeave voltasse como era.
Nao tenho a minima ideia de como fazer isso.
Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de se fazer isso, você pode utilizar useState, useReducer e até a Context API. Para facilitar usarei o [useState](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState), mas você pode pesquisar mais sobre os outros métodos na [documentação do React](https://beta.reactjs.org/).

Esse problema pode ser resolvido através da passem de propriedades (props) para os componentes. Primeiro, crie um estado e funções para mouseEnter e mouseLeave no componente Home. Sumirei que o fluxo do programa é dado por Home -> CarouselCards -> Card, nesse caso devemos passar as funções criadas através das props para o componente CarouselCards e passá-las para o componente Card em seguida.

Página Principal:

```
function Home(){
   const [info, setInfo] = useState("")

   function mouseEnter(argInfo) {
     setInfo(argInfo)
   }
   function mouseLeave() {
     setInfo("")
   }

   document.title="Spiderman Multiverse - Page d'accueil"

   return(
    <div className="body">
      <Navbar />
      <CarouselCards mouseLeave={mouseLeave} mouseEnter={mouseEnter}/>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Componente CarouselCards:

```
function CarouselCards(props){
   ...
   <Card mouseLeave={props.mouseLeave} mouseEnter={props.mouseEnter} />
   ...
}
```

Componente Card:

```
function Card({mouseLeave, mouseEnter}){
    return(
      <>
        {spidermanList.map((spiderman, index) => (
          <Link to={`/Spiderman/${spiderman.movies[0].id}`} key={index} id= 
          {`spiderman-${index + 1}`} className='card'
          onMouseEnter={() => mouseLeave(info)} // passe a informação desejada (url, imagem, cor, ...)
          onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}>
            <img src={spiderman.coverBackground} alt={spiderman.name} 
             className='card__background'/>
            <img src={spiderman.coverImg} alt={spiderman.name} 
             className='card__image'/>
            <h2 className='card__title'>{spiderman.name}</h2>
          </Link>
        ))}
     </>
   )
}
```

Como a função mouseEnter salva as informações passadas no estado info da Home essa variável pode ser utilizada para alterar seu backgroundImage. Por exemplo:

```
 // Caso URL ou imagem.
 <img src={info}/>
 // Caso uma propriedade que altere o CSS.
 <div className={`${(info == "") ? "class__bg__image__default" : "class__bg__image__alternative"} class__div__default`} />
```

Comment: Nem sei como te agradecer, nunca pensaria desta forma. Muito obrigada pela sua ajuda. Ja tenho meu id na pagina principal.

Answer (score -2):

Os dados no react devem fluir de cima para baixo, aqui como você pode ver na [documentação oficial](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down)

> Isso é comumente chamado de fluxo de dados “top-down” ou “unidirecional”. Qualquer state é sempre de propriedade de algum componente específico, e qualquer dado ou interface do usuário derivado desse state só pode afetar os componentes “abaixo” deles na árvore.

Ou seja, `Home` não pode acessar uma propriedade de `Card`, para que isso aconteça algo deve estar definido dentro do componente Home e passado como propriedade para o Card. `useRef` é uma das formas que o react tem para resolver este problema.

```
// no componente home: 
const cardRef = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
  const event = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
  const card = cardRef.current
  card.addEventListener('mouseover', event)
  return ()=>card.removeEventListener('mouseover', event)
}, []);
```

Este `cardRef` deveria caminhar até o componente que está fazendo o hover e ficar dentro de uma propriedade `ref`. Ex: `<div ref={cardRef}>...`

Comment: agradeço a sua resposta, havia conseguido pegar meu id na home com a ajuda do comentario acima, mas então pelo que entendi não é a melhor forma pra se fazer isso, certo? Vou tentar como disse, e isso tambem vai me ajudar a praticar um outro forma de conseguir o que busco.